# How to pass javaOptions to "play run" through Build.scala

Tags: playframework, sbt

I would like to pass a  `-Dconfig.file=conf/dev.conf` parameter to my application through Build.scala when I use the `run` command.

I am trying to put something like in this in my `Build.scala`:

```
val mySettings = Seq(
  (javaOptions in run) ++= Seq("-Dconfig.file=conf/dev.conf")
)

val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  mySettings: _*
)
```

But it doesn't - from what I've gathered this is because SBT doesn't fork a new JVM when I use run. Any workarounds *except* of setting an environment variable?

Comment: There is a `fork` setting in the play console. `help fork` says "If true, forks a new JVM when running.  If false, runs in the same JVM as the build.". I have no idea where or how to change that setting though.

Answer (score 2):

The matter seems to be that Play runs in the same JVM as the SBT JVM so the Java options set in SBT are not used.

You can try something like:

- Use `fork in run := true` so that a new JVM is spawn, using the Java options you give
- Launch SBT with `-Dconfig.file=conf/dev.conf`
- Set system property manually before running the app in the same JVM: `System.setProperty("config.file","conf/dev.conf")`

I'm not sure all these solutions work but it's worth trying them

Answer (score 0):

As @Sebastien Lorber has answered,

```scala
fork in run := true
```

should do the trick. Also see [How can I create a custom run task, in addition to run?](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/faq.html#how-can-i-create-a-custom-run-task-in-addition-to-run) in FAQ.